# PDF Generation from HTML using bootstrap css

Tags: pdf-generation

Can we able to generate a pdf from HTML page , where we are using two css files Style.css and bootstrap.css. Is it is feasible to render html page to pdf as it is displayed in the UI.

Comment: There are many ways to do so. Stack is a place to present what you have tried, why it failed and to ask for help on the code you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can generate a pdf from HTML page.You can generate your html page using phantom.js which provides a Javascript API to generate .pdf ,.png,.jpg etc of any static HTML page.Static page means single .html page where resources also included.The steps are as follow:

1. Download phantomjs-2.0.0-windows.zip  from http://phantomjs.org/download.html.
2. Go to the C:\Users\USER\Downloads\phantomjs-2.0.0-windows\phantomjs-2.0.0-windows\bin   ,{C:\ where library downloaded}
   3.open a terminal and jump to C:\Users\USER\Downloads\phantomjs-2.0.0-windows\phantomjs-2.0.0-windows\bin>
3. type a command on terminal: phantomjs {refer rasterize.js} "your static html page url" {target dirctory/file.extension}

for example>C:\Users\USER\Downloads\phantomjs-2.0.0-windows\phantomjs-2.0.0-windows\bin> phantomjs ../examples/rasterize.js "http://phantomjs.org/download.html" abc.pdf